# What does the --abi-compile=yes option of CUDA ptxas do (which costs registers)?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, abi, ptxas

NVIDIA CUDA's PTX optimizing assembler, `ptxas`, has the following option:

```
--abi-compile <yes|no>                              (-abi)                      
        Enable/Disable the compiling of functions using ABI.
        Default value:  'yes'.
```

What ABI is that? And what happens when you disable it? It *seems* to result in fewer registers being used, hmm...

<sub>(Question inspired by [this GTC 2011 presentation](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/register_spilling.pdf) about register spilling.)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application binary interface describe how function are called how to interface to libraries etc. What it allows is for instance to have a stack of function calls enabling for instance to call kernels from kernels, link libraries. All these features cost some registers for (mantaing the stack frame). ABIs are what makes modern software work, and programmers typically cannot opt out of them.

You can still turn abi off (and save some register), but keep in mind that linking external function as printf() won't work anymore.

[Here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/#abstracting-abi) is the link to the **official CUDA documentation** about *ABI and ptxas*. It will answer all your questions.

Comment: That seems to discuss differences in the PTX code, not in how it's compiled.

Comment: Added some details about abi and its cost in term of registers. Hope that this helps. There are few resources about the actual implementation of abi in the cuda toolchain.

Comment: So essentially +2 registers (per function?) to maintain a stack frame?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact number of register used by the ABI. It would be very instructive to compile and analyze a bunch of basic examples and look at the generated ptxas (if you want we can try to do it together). Anyway, Register and no longer a problem in newest devices, so abi will be the only option (`-abi=no` think is already deprecated).

Comment: You still only have a 64K register file on Maxwell cards, so it can still be a problem. Also, if and when we have indirect register addressing, that will be a big problem...

Comment: To give a few more examples beyond device-side `printf()`: Almost all C++ features require the ABI, seperate compilation with linking require the ABI, callbacks (e.g. for `CUFFT`) require the ABI. The ABI restricts register use, e.g. registers defined to be used for function argument passing, so it may cost more than two registers needed to build stack frames in some situations. Opinion: NVIDIA should have removed that compiler flag shortly after they introduced the ABI (with CUDA 3.0, I think) as turning off the ABI to save a few registers is a hack.